# como poner variables javascript en php

Tags: php, javascript

Hola estoy practicando con php y tengo una duda, si tengo este codigo:

```
function convertirDatos(nombre, valor) {
    return "enviarDatos.php?$nombre=" + nombre + "&$valor=" + valor;
}
```

y en el archivo recib.php tengo siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
eval("$" . $_GET["nombre"] . " = '" . $_GET['valor'] . "';");
?>
```

mi duda es: ¿hay alguna manera de hacer lo siguiente?

```
<script>
    var url = convertirDatos("nombre", "valor");;
</script>
<?php
include url;
?>
```

Comment: No, o por lo menos no deberias, lo que puedes hacer es enviar los datos que quieras enviar por medio de un formulario o ajax hacia php y recogerlos y guardarlos.

Comment: Puedes poner codigo de ejemplo?

Comment: Por cierto, porfavor lee muy bien esto de eval, consideralo: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php ahora hago un codigo ejemplo.

Comment: Ajax es la solución para esto. Todo lo demás sería recurrir a procedimientos oscuros y peligrosos por lo cual darías acceso no controlado al servidor desde el cliente. Es importante tener claro que Javascript trabaja del lado del cliente y PHP del lado del servidor y que cualquier acceso permitido no controlado al servidor puede ser catastrófico. Aquí hay varios ejemplos sobre Ajax que explican cómo funciona. Además, tiene un sinnúmero de ventajas, cuando lo descubras no podrás separarte de él :)

Comment: @A.Cedano exacto, te recomiendo seguir el consejo de A.Cedano y separar del todo php y javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar un ejemplo de aquello que deseas he creado una funcion reutilizable llamada `ajax` que te permitira hacer en cualquier momento peticiones `ajax`, por la cual usamos el metodo `GET` para enviar los datos al archivo `enviarDatos.php`, he aqui el codigo ejemplo de una peticion `GET` en `ajax`, (aunque igual podria usarse para hacer peticiones `POST`):

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

    //Ruta principal general de los archivos.
    const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost";
    
    //Contendra los parametros URL para hacer la peticion GET.
    let urlData = "";

    //Modificada para obtener solo los parametros URL y no una URL completa.
    //Es importante notar que pasamos un parametro adicional (un timestamp)
    //Esto es con el fin de evitar la cache, la cual podria ser algo molesta
    //Si estamos haciendo una peticion GET.
    function convertirDatos(nombre, valor) {
        return `nombre=${nombre}&valor=${valor}&tmstmp=${Date.now()}`;
    }

    function ajax(postMethod, url, dataToAppend){

        //Una promesa es un objeto que devuelve datos o errores en el tiempo.
        return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
            
            /*
              Creamos nuestra peticion ajax y ademas creamos la data que en un
              inicio sera un FormData, (se usa en caso de que la peticion sea
              tipo POST).
            */
            const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let data = new FormData();

            //Si la peticion es POST, añadimos la data al FormData.
            if(postMethod.toUpperCase() === "POST"){
                for(let prop in data){
                    data.append(prop, data);
                }
            }else{
                /*
                  Si la peticion es GET recreamos la URL completa pero con parametros
                  de la URL dinamicos.
                */
                data = `${url}?${dataToAppend}`;
            }
            
            /*
              Cuando la peticion cargue resolvemos la promise y entregamos la informacion
              que nos devolvio el servidor como un json, para luego poder ser usada en JS,
              en caso de error rechazamos la promesa con el error como valor devuelto.
            */
            xhttp.onload = () => res(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
            xhttp.onerror = e => rej(e);
            
            /*
              Abrimos la peticion hacia el archivo (enviarDatos.php), en caso de que
              la peticion sea POST, la URL sera igual al parametro url, de lo contrario
              la URL será la data encolada con los parametros que habiamos obtenido.
            */
            xhttp.open(postMethod, postMethod.toUpperCase() === "POST" ? url : data, true);

            /*
              En caso de ser una peticion GET debemos añadirle a ajax un header llamado
              Content-Type, con su valor application/x-www-form-urlencoded, de lo contrario
              podria haber errores a la hora de hacer la peticion GET, luego simplemente
              enviamos la peticion.
            */
            if(postMethod.toUpperCase() === "GET"){
                xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhttp.send();
            }else{
                //En caso de ser una peticion POST enviamos el FormData.
                xhttp.send(data);
            }
            
        });
        
    }

    //Obtenemos la informacion de los parametros en una URL.
    urlData = convertirDatos("Juan", 16);
    
    //then y catch hacen parte de promise, usamos nuestra funcion ajax
    //Para enviar datos hacia enviarDatos.php y luego cuando todo haya
    //sucedido con exito entramos al then, donde habra la data traida por
    //el servidor, en caso de error, entramos al catch y mostramos el error.
    ajax("GET", `${SERVER_URL}/enviarDatos.php`, urlData).then(res =>{
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(e =>{
        console.error(e);
    });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ajax example</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Y en la parte de PHP (`enviarDatos.php`) tendriamos lo siguiente:

```
<?php

    /*
      Cabeceras adicionales para evitar problemas de origines cruzados,
      para declarar el tipo de dato que será devuelto hacia el cliente (json)
      y tambien para declarar el encoding de la respuesta.
    */
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

    //Obtenemos nuestros valores
    $nombre = $_GET["nombre"];
    $valor = $_GET["valor"];

    //Devolvemos la respuesta hacia el cliente como un json.
    //Los parametros devueltos pueden ser lo que deseemos.
    echo json_encode(["status" => "OK!"]);

?>
```

La explicacion del codigo esta en el mismo codigo, por supuesto aquí en stackoverflow esto no funcionara si lo ejecutas, pero podrás probarlo tu mismo en el ordenador.

Comment: esto es con JQuery?

Comment: Para nada ese es "ajax sin usar librerias", ajax en su mas puro estilo, el ajax de jQuery es un poco distinto en algunas cosas... pero son esencialmente lo mismo (hacen la misma funcion), lo que pasa es que jQuery tiene integrado su propio metodo ajax que nos hace mas cortas las cosas.

Comment: Disculpa intento hacer un ```echo nombre ``` y  me  sale:
```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token J in JSON at position 16```

Comment: Por eso se encuentra la linea json_encode, porque se supone que lo que debes mandar desde el servidor es un json, no una variable, se soluciona formateando esa data y enviandola como json.